# Can you give me an example word that is in the language $L = \{w | w ∈ \{a,b\}^∗ ∧ |w|_a = |w|_b\} $

Tags: formal-languages

Again, the language is $L = \{w | w ∈ \{a,b\}^∗ ∧ |w|_a = |w|_b\} $
Now I'm unsure about what the '*' indicates. Whether it means that either a or b can be repeated, or only one of them or if you can repeat a pattern made of a and b.
An explanation would also be appreciated but I thought one or more examples of what would be a word in the language and what not would be quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language $L$ contains

- all strings $w$ over the alphabet $\{a,b\}$ such  that
- the number of $a$'s equals the number of
  $b$'s in $w$.

Like $aaabbb$ or $abababab$.

Answer (score 3):

Check your definitions: $*$ is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

So, $\{a,b\}^*$ is the set of all finite strings over alphabet $\{a,b\}$.